# Launch apps from the Lockscreen

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, theos, cydia-substrate

As of right now I am using `[SpringBoard launchApplicationWithIdentifier: suspended:]` to launch applications from the lockscreen. If there is no passcode, this works fine for the lockscreen. However, if there is a passcode, it does not launch.

How do you prompt for the passcode and then launch the application if the device has a passcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the app you need to launch and then after a successful unlock, launch the app.  You can see this being successfully done in [AnyLockApp](https://github.com/nickfrey/AnyLockApp/blob/master/Tweak.xm). It is important to note that iOS7's replacement for SBAwayController is SBLockScreenViewController